# Overlaying two raster images with no spatial reference

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, georeferencing

I have two images (X-Ray and Neutron Tomography Scan) of a human bone fragment.  I want to use ArcGIS 10.2 to accurately overlay (geo-reference) these two images which have no spatial coordinates. any suggestions please ?

Comment: Are the images pixel-for-pixel matches or does a pixel in the one image map onto an entirely different pixel in the other image? If the latter is the case, then you might have to perform pixel matching (either automated or by digitizing tie points between the images) and resampling to do this.

Comment: I think this should "just work" and be no different to the steps used to co-locate two scanned aerial photos of the same area at different times.  Have you tried it and found something that does not appear to work?  Can you perhaps include two images as pictures in your question to demonstrate what you may perceive to be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

In fact ArcGIS is geo(spatial) data processing software. By the way, overlaying one over another depends on the image dimension of the images(s) is being imported in arc map.If images with same dimensions are imported then these images overlay one over another.In this case arc map creates two files (.xml and .ovr)for each image. You need to just drag and drop on the arc map.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

If you are with different dimensions then i suggest bringing them into same dimension( by several ways e.g cropping, image re-sizing, maintaining dimension when image is captured etc.)